# How to import and load images from redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I'm working on this project where I need to load some images which are stored in my redux store. I'm using the `useSelector` function to get the images however they are not showing in my browser.
Here is my code:

**Review.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

// CSS
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

// Material UI
// Layout
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

// Text
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  title: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },

}));

function Review() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const product = useSelector((state) => state.productReducer);

  return (
    <Grid>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
        Final Product
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom className={classes.title}>
            {product.Name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom>Price {product.Price}</Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom>Category {product.Category}</Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom>Ships to {product.Ships_to}</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} container justify="space-evenly">
          <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
            Display Pics:
          </Typography>
          <img src={product.Pic1} width="200" height="200" alt="" />
          <img src={product.Pic2} width="200" height="200" alt="" />
          <img src={product.Pic3} width="200" height="200" alt="" />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default Review;
```

**ProductReducer.js**

```
// Imports
// Actions
import {
  ADD_PRODUCT_DETAILS,
  ADD_PRODUCT_DISPLAY,
  DELETE_PRODUCT,
} from "../Actions/ProductTypes";

// Defining Initial State
var initialState = {
  Brand: null,
  Name: "",
  Price: 0.0,
  Category: "",
  Ships_to: [],
  Pic1: null,
  Pic2: null,
  Pic3: null,
};

const productReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action["type"]) {
    case ADD_PRODUCT_DETAILS:
      state = initialState;

      state["Brand"] = action["Brand"];
      state["Name"] = action["Name"];
      state["Price"] = action["Price"];
      state["Category"] = action["Category"];
      state["Ships_to"] = action["Ships_to"];

      return state;
    case ADD_PRODUCT_DISPLAY:
      state["Pic1"] = action["Pic1"];
      state["Pic2"] = action["Pic2"];
      state["Pic3"] = action["Pic3"];

      return state;
    case DELETE_PRODUCT:
      state = initialState;

      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default productReducer;
```

**index.js**

```
...
//  Imports
// Redux Modules
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

// Reducers
import authReducer from "./AuthReducer";
import userReducer from "./UserReducer";

import productReducer from "./ProductReducer";

//  Defining RootReducer
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  authReducer,
  userReducer,
  productReducer,
});

// Defining LocalStorage
function saveToLocalStorage(state) {
  try {
    const serialisedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem("persistantState", serialisedState);
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  }
}

function loadFromLocalStorage() {
  try {
    const serialisedState = localStorage.getItem("persistantState");
    if (serialisedState === null) return undefined;
    return JSON.parse(serialisedState);
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
    return undefined;
  }
}

//  Defining Redux Store
export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  loadFromLocalStorage(),
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

// Persisting state using { LocalStorage }
store.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(store.getState()));
```

How do I get the images to show on my browser can anyone tell me?

**Edit**
Here is `Display Form.js`

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import { ADD_PRODUCT_DISPLAY } from "../../../Actions/ProductTypes";

// CSS
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

// Material UI
// Layout
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

// Text
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

// Input & Icons
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
  },
  input: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0),
  },
}));

function DisplayForm() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const product = useSelector((state) => state.productReducer);

  const [file1, setFile1] = useState("");
  const [file2, setFile2] = useState("");
  const [file3, setFile3] = useState("");

  const handleFile1Change = (e) => {
    setFile1(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleFile2Change = (e) => {
    setFile2(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleFile3Change = (e) => {
    setFile3(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } };
    const URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/product-create/";

    let formData = new FormData();

    dispatch({
      type: ADD_PRODUCT_DISPLAY,
      Pic1: file1,
      Pic2: file2,
      Pic3: file3,
    });
  };

  return (
    <Grid>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
        Product Display
      </Typography>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={3}
        direction="column"
        justify="center"
        alignItems="flex-start"
      >
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <label>
            <input
              accept="image/*"
              className={classes.input}
              id="post-image"
              onChange={handleFile1Change}
              name="image"
              type="file"
            />
          </label>

          <Typography variant="p" component="text" gutterBottom>
            Please select a picture to display your product
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <input
            accept="image/*"
            className={classes.input}
            id="post-image"
            onChange={handleFile2Change}
            name="image"
            type="file"
          />

          <Typography variant="p" component="text" gutterBottom>
            Please select another picture to display your product
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <input
            accept="image/*"
            className={classes.input}
            id="post-image"
            onChange={handleFile3Change}
            name="image"
            type="file"
          />

          <Typography variant="p" component="text" gutterBottom>
            Please select the final picture to display your product
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit Product Display</Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default DisplayForm;
```

Comment: I'm confused about the way you've written the reducer. There should be a `payload` in action param. Could you share the code part where you use dispatch the action `ADD_PRODUCT_DISPLAY`?

Comment: Are you storing the urls to the images in store or the full images? Full images generally shouldn't go in store, especially seeing as you write your full store to localstorage, that has a limit of 10MB you will very quickly hit

Comment: @parkourkarthik I did that in the edit section

Comment: @phry look at the edit section :)

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying your current state here, which is considered a bug and never allowed in Redux reducers. You are just modifying state, which means that React will never detect that a change happened and never re-render with the new state.

You must not do `state.x = ...` in old-style "vanilla" Redux. You could so if you were using [Modern Redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) style reducers, but not in old-style Redux as you are using here.
(To get into modern Redux, follow [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) )

Here, your `ADD_PRODUCT_DETAILS` would need to look like

```js
    case ADD_PRODUCT_DETAILS:
      return {
        ...initialState,
        Brand: action.Brand,
        Name: action.Name,
        Price: action.Price,
        Category: action.Category,
        Ships_to: action.Ships_to
      }
```

and ADD_PRODUCT_DISPLAY:

```js
    case ADD_PRODUCT_DISPLAY:
      return {
        ...state,
        Pic1: action.Pic1,
        Pic2: action.Pic2,
        Pic3: action.Pic3,
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes but that still does not solve my problem of images not showing when using those in redux.